# custom query in Magento to insert data to database

Tags: mysql, database, magento, magento-1.7

This is the table structure of the payment_customer table.

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `payment_customer` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `added_date` datetime NOT NULL,
  `merchant_reference_no` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
  `amount` int(10) NOT NULL,
  `order_desc` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=5 ;
```

Above table stores the data about the customers who made payments. I use below query to insert data to the table in my custom payment gateway module.

```
$write = Mage::getSingleton('core/resource')->getConnection('core_write');
$sql  = " INSERT INTO payment_customer ('id', 'added_date', 'merchant_reference_no', 'amount', 'order_desc') VALUES (NULL, '2013-02-13 00:00:00', '233AX23', '200', 'test'); ";
$write->query($sql);
```

Then I tried

```
$write = Mage::getSingleton('core/resource')->getConnection('core_write');
$sql  = " INSERT INTO sampath_payment_customer ('id', 'added_date', 'merchant_reference_no', 'amount', 'order_desc') VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?,?); ";
$write->query($sql, array('NULL', '2013-02-13 00:00:00', '233AX23', '200', 'test'));
$write->save();
```

But both does not insert any data instead it gives me below error message.

[image]

How can I fix this ?

Comment: Check error report what error are you getting?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you check the file with error log record number in **var/report/1149745463637**
It will give exact idea about the error.
Hope this will help you.